# lambda function in Python

Tags: python, lambda

I found a interesting behavior of lambda function in Python.

If I do,

```
lambda_funcs = []
for i in range(10):
    lambda_func = lambda x:x[i]
    lambda_funcs.append(lambda_func)

X = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print lambda_funcs[0](X)
```

It throws an error: IndexError: list index out of range.

This code aims to create 10 lambda functions each of which returns i-th element. But, all lambda_func in the above code attempts to retrieve 10th element.

To make it work, I found that the following definition is a right way:

```
lambda_func = (lambda j: lambda x: x[j])(i)
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on inside lambda evaluation in Python?

Comment: change to `lambda_func = lambda x, i=i:x[i]`

Comment: classic lazy evaluation issue where `i` is the same for all lambdas

Comment: Try printing the value of `i` in your lambda function

Comment: @eyllanesc they already showed a more "correct" solution, `(lambda j: lambda x: x[j])(i)`

Comment: This is due to the late-binding behavior of Python closures (so this has nothing to do with `lambda` per se). Here is a very good explanation: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures